# Computer cannot resolve Firebase domain

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, dns, domain

I am currently debugging a chrome extension that I wrote, which uses Google Firebase for its authentication and its realtime database. Now, the extension is already distributed to a number of people, and one of the users have reported a peculiar problem.

Specifically, the user is able to log in, but unable to access the database. In the screenshot below, you can see that the login request completes with HTTP code 200, but the database request is always pending, and eventually stalls and fails.

[image]

I have tried to ping the domain, and it turns out even outside of the browser(in the command prompt), the system cannot even resolve the domain!

[image]

I can confirm the following:

- **It's not a bug in my code, and the links are correct**, since the same copy of extension is running faultlessly on many other computers, including mine. The login credential (and therefore the database access token) is valid too.
- **Other computers in the same house runs the same extension faultlessly**, therefore ruling out the possibility of a network or router issue. It has to be something local.
- **I have turned off antivirus softwares and firewalls** (in this case Bitdefender), and nothing changes - still unable to resolve domain name.
- **The hosts file is fine**. No one tempered with the hosts file.

Can anyone suggest other reasons why this could be, or in what directions should I be looking? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you ping the URL but without the `https://` prefix. If you do an `nslookup`, then run `lserver 8.8.8.8`, and then from there ping the domain without the `https://` prefix, what result do you get? I would also admin elevate run `ipconfig /flushdns` and then try to ping it. Lastly, reboot the computer and then when it's back up and you're on it, see if you can ping it. If you determine you can ping but not get it to work after all that, I'd sign onto the machine with a new account (or create a new profile) and see if it work, and if so, assume it's a corrupt Windows user profile.

Comment: You might also ensure that that machine is using TLS 1.2 by default and look into turning on FIPS compliant ciphers, reboot, and then see if that does it. If so some reason it's sending TLS 1.0 or something older and it does not change over to TLS 1.2 and the https server requires it, that could be what's up too. I have seen this before or something along those lines based on memory. See this post for configuration detail: https://www.hpe.com/psnow/resources/ebooks/a00110924en_us_v1/s_setup-fips-windows-server.html starting at #6 and not the Linux or IIS stuff above it.